# planetary scale motor

Tags: planets, gyroscopes

A spinning mass of a motor has a gyroscopic effect when moved. As the mas and size of the motor approaches the size of the planet it sits on, what kind of effects would this cause to the planet?

Comment: Consider editting out the second question, because it is opinion-based (i.e., off topic). The first question is ok, and it might get interesting answers, but if you keep the second question the post might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the mass on the rotating rod is the same as the mass of the planet the system would behave similar to a binary star - the circles which both's paths go would have the same radius and velocity, since every action causes an equal reaction. The force acting on the mass and the planet would be the same, so if the mass is also the same so is the acceleration.

[image: binary]

The first sphere depicts the earth, the second one the mass on the rod, and the rod connecting mass and planet has to be imagined and goes through the center where the red cross sits.

If the mass is spinnig around it's own center instead of being attached to a rotating rod (like in this video: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cRb0xvPJ2M&t=1m10s)), the planet it sits on would spin in the exact opposite direction than the mass, so if the mass rotates from it's West to it's East, the planet will rotate from East to West (assuming that the spinning mass is attached either to the North- or South-pole of the planet)

For the second question you already deleted (what would be the use of such a machine): you could slow down or speed up the rotation of your planet, so if you think 24 hours per day are not enough you could add or substract as many hours as you like. (in principle you can also do this with a small gyroscope, but then it would also take forever to create some measurable effect).